# Count subject wise preferencewise count in my sql

Tags: mysql, database

i have three tables :

Table1:
student_tbl

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | AAAA |
| 2 | BBBB |

table2:
majorsubjects

| id | subName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | sub1 |
| 2 | sub2 |
| 3 | sub3 |
| 4 | sub4 |

table 3

| id | subject_id | student_id | Preferences |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 5 | 4 | 2 | 2 |
| 5 | 4 | 2 | 3 |

Note: student has three preferences
I want to have cout of subjects preference wise: like:

| SubName | Preference 1 Cout | preference 2 | preference 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sub1 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| sub2 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT subName, SUM(IF(t.Preferences = 1, 1, 0)) 'Preference 1',
SUM(IF(t.Preferences = 2, 1, 0)) 'Preference 2',
SUM(IF(t.Preferences = 3, 1, 0)) 'Preference 3',
 FROM majorsubjects m, table3 t WHERE 
m.id = t.subject_id group by t.subject_id
```

It will be something like this.

Comment: If you want the preferences column dynamic, you need to loop it in the code and put variable in IF condition. Thanks

Comment: Thank you Ashutosh Goyal for your solutions! Great

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: the query worked for me. thanks Ashtosh Goyal